# jQuery opens the last class popup given to it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Let me explain the title. I have multiple `divs` with same structure, something like this:

```
<div class="description" >
    <div class="popup">
    hey
    </div>
    <button class="details" onclick="openpopup">details </button>
</div>
<div class="description" >
    <div class="popup">
    hey
    </div>
    <button class="details" onclick="openpopup">details </button>
</div>
<div class="description" >
    <div class="popup">
    hey
    </div>
    <button class="details" onclick="openpopup">details </button>
</div>
```

And this is the `jquery` that i wrote:

```
$(".details").click(function () {
    $(".popup").css("display","block");
});
```

But it only shows the last popup no matter which button is clicked, so I know what's the problem but I don't know how to fix it.
And I can't send different id's for each of the `divs` cause they're gonna be dynamic and come from a server, so I can't use something like that either.

Comment: So do you want to open all divs or their respective div only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way of fixing it is to reach to parent and then find its children popup block. Try like this:

```
$(".details").click(function () {
    $(this).parent().find(".popup").css("display","block");
});
```